# How to test a particular jsx file within localhost?

Tags: reactjs, localhost, next.js

Below is the screenshot of my working directory.

[image]

I run `yarn dev` command to start local host to test my site. After the local host is set up I could test every jsx file which is under `pages` folder by going to their respective link. Like if I  want to test `campaigns.jsx` file I go to http://localhost:3000/campaigns and everything works file and even for any other jsx file under `pages` folder everything works fine.

But similarly if I want to test jsx files within `components` folder and go to their respective link like http://localhost:3000/topnav, I get `404 | This page could not be found.` error message.

So could anyone tell me is there any possible way to test jsx files which are under `components` folder as I'm new to this REACT world.

Comment: There's no inherent way to do this. The reason it works for the pages is because that's how `next.js` works, it puts those files at those routes. For just general components that won't work. You should try the storybook library, it does exactly what you want: https://storybook.js.org/

Comment: No other possible way ?